# Facebook API: replacement for /me/home to get user's news feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I run a small Facebook app that uses its users' news feed via the [`/me/home` API endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/home) and the [`read_stream` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-read_stream). (Facebook doesn't actually grant `read_stream` to plain old normal apps, so my users create their own FB app and use its key/secret, which works.)

Sadly, Facebook is [turning off the `/me/home` endpoint altogether](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations) in two months, on Oct. 6. I get their intent, but I'm hoping there's some way to keep my app running. Is there any other way to get a user's news feed, ie posts from their friends and people they follow?

Just public posts is fine; that's all /me/home has returned for the last year and change anyway, since the v2.0 upgrade. I'm even OK with scraping HTML, as long as it's accessible an access token instead of a session cookie. (Seems unlikely.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use `/me/feed`. With `user_posts` permission from your current user, it will get you their own posts. How much information about/by friends is visible, will depend on whether those are also using your app and have also given it permission.

Comment: thanks @CBroe! `/me/feed` isn't really what i'm looking for though. [from the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed): _The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by this person, or by others on this person's profile._

Comment: That’s what you _can_ get. Getting a user’s whole feed, including posts by others, pages etc., is not possible any more.

Comment: yup, i understand that's their intent, as mentioned in the OP. i'm just hoping for a workaround, whether it's another API endpoint or scraping HTML or something else altogether. there may not be one, but people here are resourceful, so who knows!

Comment: There is no workaround. No other endpoint, and scraping is not allowed (without Facebook's express written permission).

Answer (score 2):

As commenters said, facebook is turning it off for good because they want to use the me/feed. Thats because of the privacy discussions facebook has right now, the me/home did just reveal too much information about others. I don't know where it was but I heard of a lawsuit regarding this API endpoint.

Comment: thanks for the answer! as i mentioned, i do understood what they're doing, and their intent behind it. i was looking for an actual workaround, if any.